# Switching from Heroku to Docker Platform Cycle.io problems

Tags: git, heroku, docker, devops

Ok I'm a total noob at devops but please bear with me, I've tried my best to explain my predicament.

Now I have a Java Application (currently hosted on heroku) with the code visible at GitHub. The code visible however, cannot be directly deployed. There are 2-3 privileged files like `applications.properties` which contains our , a couple other Auth files etc which cannot be put up on GitHub for obvious security reasons. We are also using a MySQL database provided to us by the ClearDB plugin by Heroku.

The workaround for now is that these files are present only in the Heroku git remote and set to go. Whenever we want to redeploy, we switch to the Heroku remote, pull code changes from master and push it to auto deploy.

Now, we are shifting from Heroku to either [Cycle.io](https://cycle.io) or [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/). Setting up an AWS would be pretty straigtforward but Cycle.io uses docker images. I had a couple of questions here.

1. Cycle.io provides us with a deployment and I don't see no talk about any database being provided. What/where do we get ourselves a DB from? What are our options? Cycle.io allows us to create `Environments`. To quote

> Environments allow users to organize groups of related containers.
>   When an environment is created, Cycle automatically creates a private
>   network to connect the containers inside.

Does this setup some kind of Linux environment where I can setup a MySQL database? Do I have to setup a Docker Image for a MySQL image and allow the code image to communicate it with it?

2. What would be the best workflow if we consider using Docker images for cycle.io? Would it be something like this?

   - Build a docker image on my system that works
   - Push it to Docker Hub to a private repository and allow cycle.io, which integrates with docker hub to pick it up from there
3. Cycle says

> Deploy your containers in two simple steps: simply pull your
>   production-ready images from Docker Hub or any Git repo and click
>   import image.

How on earth do I host docker images on GitHub. I mean you shouldn't really be hosting files on GitHub right? Docker Hub makes more sense. Or does this mean it fetches the code and compiles it into a docker image?

4. What's the best way to have a 'private' git branch like the heroku one? I know I would like to add a private remote but like how do I do it? Should I just let the public branch and keep like a private dropbox of the private files?

Answer (score 0):

1. There are various ways to "get" a db. The simplest one is to use some kind of managed solution, for mysql there are many options - the most popular ones are cloud sql by google and RDS by AWS. You can also install a MySQL DB as a container, but I don't know if Cycle.io offers that service. Your best bet is to approach Cycle.io with that question and ask which mysql solution best integrates with their product, or choose AWS (elastic beanstalk is a great service for running docker containers, and can provide a mysql instance as an data layer)
2. The flow you suggested works. A better flow will include some kind of CI/CD pipeline which can build your image automatically when you push code to github, than deploy it to AWS/cycle.io. We are using CircleCI, which offer 1 free container for small builds, and is great for these purposes.
3. You never put the actual docker image on github. What you should do is add a dockerfile to the repo, and the image is built from that. I'm guessing cycle.io are offering you this option - automatically building the image from the dockerfile you put in the repo. This is the way we are building our images with CirclCI.
4. Deploy keys are useful for this purpose. You create one and allow only authorized services to communicate with your repo using that key.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me some insight. However, I still don't have a solution for my private files (the application.properties one) I can't have this on the repository and how on earth do I incorporate this into an automatic build?

Comment: This practice is known as secret management, and there are a few tools designated specifically for that. You can check out hashicorp's Vault for an example of such tool - https://www.vaultproject.io/

Comment: I have my teammate put up a question regarding the same here http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/336959/integrate-private-files-for-open-source-application-code-in-devops-pipeline

Comment: Hopefully you could help out?